# Model's training highly dependent on weights initialitation. How to deal with it?

Tags: time-series, neural-networks, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I am training a simple RNN model in `keras` to predict a time series.

The time series I am considering is just a sine function

$$
f(t) = \sin \left(\frac{3}{10}t\right)
$$

The task to solve is the following:

> Given a timeseries of 90 time steps, predict the next 10 time steps.

I am generating my training set by sampling from

$$
f(t) = \sin \left(\frac{3}{10}(t+\epsilon)\right)
$$

where $\epsilon$ is just a noise term that shifts the series. I have added the noise to have a good training sample.

***Question***

I train my model for 10 epochs. I notice that sometimes the predictions are actually very good. Some other times, if I retrain the same model with the same dataset, the predictions are very bad. This has to do with the randomness of weights initialisations, but I was hoping that the training algorithm would have found the "best" solution anyway, irrespectively of the initial weights. When I say "best" solution, I mean a class of solutions whose variance is small. How can I deal with random weights initialisation? Do I need to add some regulation terms to my network?

I know that I can define an ensemble of multiple models in order to cope with weights initialisation. However, this is a very simple problem, and I was expecting to be able to solve it with a single simple model.

***Description of the model and code***

You can find a Jupyter notebook [here](https://github.com/doogersPy/files/blob/main/dependence_on_initial_weights.ipynb) .

My training sample will be time series of lenght 90 and the targets will be the value of the series at the 91st step.

I will predict the 10 steps by first predicting the 91st step. Then, I will plug it in the sample. I will select the last 90 terms and predict the 92nd step and so on.

The model I am using is very simple, it is a stack of two RNN layers and a Dense layer.

```
class TwoLSTM:
    def __init__(self, n_units_1:int, n_units_2:int):
        self.n_units_1 = n_units_1
        self.n_units_2 = n_units_2
        self.model = None
        
        self.build()
        
    def build(self):
        self.model = keras.models.Sequential([
        keras.layers.LSTM(self.n_units_1, return_sequences=True, input_shape=[None, 1]),
        keras.layers.LSTM(self.n_units_2),
        keras.layers.Dense(1)])
        
        self.model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer="adam")
    
    def fit(self, train:tuple, test:tuple, epochs:int, batch_size:int=32,verbose=0):
        X_train, y_train = train
        X_test, y_test = test
        
        callbacks = [
        keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=10, mode='min', restore_best_weights=True)]
        history = self.model.fit(X_train, y_train, 
                        epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, 
                        validation_data=(X_test, y_test), callbacks=callbacks,
                        shuffle=True, verbose=verbose)
        return history
```

The first training of 10 epochs returns the following prediction of a series in the training set

[image]

and the log of the loss function during training are

[image]

Then, I train again the same model (by redefining it again; I don't use the best weights of the first run as starting point) and this time I get very good predictions and loss functions

[image]

and

[image]